# Speed difference between inserting html and changing display style property

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, single-page-application

Assuming you have a relatively small piece of HTML (let's say under 100 tags and <4KB in size) and you want to occasionally display and hide it from your user (think menu, modal... etc).

Is the fastest approach to hide and show it using css, such as:

```
//Hide:
document.getElementById('my_element').style.display = 'none';

//Show:
document.getElementById('my_element').style.display = 'block';
```

Or to insert and remove it:

```
//Hide
document.getElementById('my_element_container').innerHTML = '';

//Show:
const my_element_html = {contents of the element};
document.getElementById('my_element_container').innerHTML = my_element_html;

// Note: insertAdjacentHTML is obviously faster when the container has other elements, but I'm showcasing this using innerHTML to get my point across, not necessarily because it's always the most efficient of the two.
```

Obviously, this can be benchmarked on a case by case basis, but, with some many browser versions and devices out there, any benchmarks that I'd be able to run in a reasonable amount of time aren't that meaningful.

I've been unable to find any benchmarks related to this subject.

Are there any up to date benchmarks comparing the two approaches? Is there any consensus from browsers developers as to which should, generally speaking, be preferred when it comes to speed.

Comment: What does JSPerf say - my gut feeling is with any significant HTML content, there will be an order of magnitude difference between show/hide and remove and insert

Comment: Both, changing the display and remving the innerHTML will cause a reflow, those are bad for performance, can you use visibility to hide the element? That would be easier on the browser.

Comment: I would go with the first one because you dont have to rebuild the content every time.

Comment: @Luca In my experience the behavior of elements when changing the `visibility` property is very unreliable and hard to understand and design properly around. So the extra loading speed there never seemed worth it considering the mental overhead.

Comment: @Luca, also, considering that they both cause a reflow, would that essentially mean they are similar in performance ?

Comment: Both of your examples cause a reflow, yes, depending on how heavy the elements are that you reinserting they also probably have the same perf.

Answer (score 1):

In principle, DOM manipulation is slower than toggling `display` property of existing nodes. And I could stop my answer here, as this is technically correct.

---

However, repaint and reflow of the page is typically way slower and both your methods trigger it so you could be looking at:

- display toggle: 1 unit
- DOM nodes toggle: 2 units
- repaint + reflow of page: 100 units

Which leaves you comparing 101 units with 102 units, instead of comparing 3 with 4 (or 6 with 7). I'm not saying that's the order of magnitude, it really depends on the actual DOM tree of your real page, but chances are it's close to the figures above.

If you use methods like: `visibility:hidden` or `opacity:0`, it will be **way faster**, not to mention `opacity` is *animatable*, which, in modern UIs, is preferred.

A few resources:

- [Taming huge collections of DOMs](https://codeburst.io/taming-huge-collections-of-dom-nodes-bebafdba332)
- [Render-tree Construction, Layout, and Paint](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/critical-rendering-path/render-tree-construction)
- [How Browsers Work: Behind the scenes of modern web browsers](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/internals/howbrowserswork/)
- [An introduction to Web Performance and the Critical Rendering Path](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/an-introduction-to-web-performance-and-the-critical-rendering-path-ce1fb5029494)
- [Understanding the critical rendering path, rendering pages in 1 second](https://medium.com/@luisvieira_gmr/understanding-the-critical-rendering-path-rendering-pages-in-1-second-735c6e45b47a)

Web performance, much like web development, is not a "press this button" process. You need to try, fail, learn, try again, fail again...

---

If your elements are always the same, you might find out (upon testing) caching them inside a variable is much faster than recreating them when your show method is called.

Testing is quite simple:

- place each of the methods inside a separate function;
- log the starting time (using `performance.now()`);
- use each method `n` times, where `n` is: 100, 1e3, 1e4,... 1e7
- log finishing time for each test (or difference from its starting time)

Compare. You will notice conclusions drawn from 100 test are quite different than the ones from 1e7 test.

To go even deeper, you can test differences for different methods when showing and for different methods when hiding. You could test rendering elements hidden and toggle their display afterwards. Get creative. Try anything you can think of, even if it seems silly or doesn't make much sense.

That's how you learn.

Comment: So, tl;dr: It depends, so test it. Which is the answer to pretty much every performance question on SO :).

Comment: @HereticMonkey, pretty much. I'd take out the "on SO" part, though.